# Is it legal to download a picture from clients device to company computers?

Tags: law

In reference to the patent: [US9396354](https://www.google.com/patents/US9396354)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking if US9396354 in some ways prevents you from downloading pictures to a company owned computer. The answer is yes it is quite legal to do so. The patent concerns a method for automatically blurring faces found on downloaded images so that privacy protections are honored.